# Unclear definition of "N-way ANOVA" and "N-way mixed ANOVA"

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am confused about the definition of "N-way ANOVA" and "N-way mixed ANOVA". Are they two totally disjoint classes? Or does "N-way ANOVA" includes "N-way mixed ANOVA"?

For example, when I am referring to a "three-way ANOVA", does it mean I am having three between-subject factors and no within-subject factor? (Sometimes I see this is further specified as "between-subjects three way ANOVA" rather than just "three-way ANOVA")

Or is saying a "three-way ANOVA" not enough for clarifying whether if there is any with-subject factor?

Answer (score 0):

Mixed ANOVA means that there are both within- and between- subject variables.

Just saying n-way ANOVA is a confusing description of your analysis...as you said, sometimes people specify "between-subjects three way ANOVA".